# Flutter not rendering UI in real device on release apk

Tags: flutter, user-interface, render, release-apk

I have been writting ui for my app, it was ok while building in debug mode. But when I built release apk, UI getting smudged, and Text isn't shown. Widgets are being rendered not as expected and their size being rendered not correctly. I checked it in different phones but result is the same. Is there a problem in my code or it's flutter's inner bug? Has anyone seen this before?

[**It's in release apk**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piBmI.jpg)

[**It's in debug apk**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODuaI.jpg)

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:rx_shared_preferences/rx_shared_preferences.dart';
```

````
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 12.0),
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: rxPrefs.getStringStream('firstName'),
          builder: (context, snapshot) => Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.w, vertical: 12.h),
            child: Text(
              '${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.hello} ${snapshot.data ?? ''}',
              style: AppTextStyles.headline,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14.w, vertical: 12.h),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => context.push(SearchPage.route),
            child: Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(Icons.search),
                    const SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                    Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.search,
                      style: AppTextStyles.title0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        FutureBuilder(
            future: ApiService.getInstance().getPromos(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Promo> promos = snapshot.data as List<Promo>;

                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.w, vertical: 12.h),
                  child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                      height: widget.mediaQuery.size.height * .25,
                      viewportFraction: 1,
                    ),
                    itemCount: promos.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int realIndex) => Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                      height: widget.mediaQuery.size.height * .25,
                      width: widget.mediaQuery.size.width,
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: promos[index].image,
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.w, vertical: 12.h),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                height: widget.mediaQuery.size.height * .25,
                width: widget.mediaQuery.size.width,
                // alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Card(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
              );
            }),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.w, vertical: 12.h),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                AppLocalizations.of(context)!.categories,
                style: AppTextStyles.title0,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => context.push(CategoriesPage.route),
                child: Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.seeAll,
                  style: AppTextStyles.title0.copyWith(color: AppColors.grey),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Consumer<CategoryBloc>(
          builder: (context, bloc, child) => SizedBox(
            height: widget.mediaQuery.size.height * .2,
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.w),
              itemCount: bloc.categories.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => CategoryCard(category: bloc.categories[index]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.w, vertical: 12.h),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                AppLocalizations.of(context)!.popular,
                style: AppTextStyles.title0,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => context.push(ProductsPage.route),
                child: Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.seeAll,
                  style: AppTextStyles.title0.copyWith(color: AppColors.grey),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Consumer<ProductBloc>(
            builder: (context, bloc, child) =>
                Column(children: bloc.products.take(4).map((e) => ProductWidget(product: e)).toList())),
        const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
      ],
    );
  }```
````

Comment: This isn't a Framework's bug. Your issue is probably related to your AppLocalizations setup. Did you try to run your app with the ```flutter run --release``` command and to check if you had any logs ?

Comment: Yes, I tried and there isn't anything strange. In logs, I have two lines "D/FlutterGeolocator( 5373): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 5373): Binding to location service." that's all.

Comment: Tried to remove AppLocalizations usage even after it, the issue remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, the widgets weren't rendering because of `const` constructors of class-based widgets. To resolve this issue there're two ways, first to remove `const` before widget constructor and usage, second to remove `screen_util` or another package that generates value dynamically.
Here's the link where I found the original solution https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_screenutil/issues/341, https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_screenutil/issues/350.

Answer (score 2):

For me, have to wait for preferredOrientations and add await of 150 milliseconds before runApp(). because some phones will launch the app too fast which can cause the UI to not be ready yet. like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 150));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: This was specific problem with Flutter, which allowed using const with widgets using variable values. This problem is avoided by default because dart extension and linter will point to you you can't use const with variable.