# Flutter: UI not always rendering correctly, when opening app in Smartphone via browser in mobile mode

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile, rendering, multiplatform

I'm building a multiplatform app, whose web version is hosted at firebase. When I'm opening this site in my android smartphone (in mobile mode, not as desktop website) sometimes it's rendering correctly, but sometimes it doesn't. For example, there is a floating action button which isn't showing though it's there. You can tap on it, and then its tooltip is showing, and its functionality is working fine, but so to say it's invisible. The app bars and a CircularProgressIndicator are also invisible.

In debug, it's always rendering correctly. Both - the web and the mobile version.
I also installed the app on my smartphone, and it's also always rendering correctly.

I removed the "const" from constructors of class-based widgets which was a solution to a similar problem ([Flutter not rendering UI in real device on release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382151/flutter-not-rendering-ui-in-real-device-on-release-apk)), but it didn't work for me.
Putting some delay before runApp did not work either.

It's not so easy to reproduce the error. When entering the appsite for the first time, everything is fine. The error doesn't appear while using the app. You have to let the screen of your phone turn off and wait for a while. Then after turning the screen on again and reopening the site, sometimes the rendering isn't correct and then stays incorrect.

Does anyone have the same problem? Or even a solution?

Comment: update: "flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit" seems to work for me